# How to write a SQL Server query to get a group

Tags: sql-server

I have a table `rsPhotos` that has 4 columns: `picID`, `huntID`, `photo`, `D_hunt`.

The `photo` column has many different jpgs, the `huntID` column is relative to the `photo`s but there are many different `huntID`'s.

I just want  **ONE** `photo` for each `huntID`.

I have tried the `min` function with groups but get errors mixing text with nums. Tried `TOP`, doesn't work for me.

Can someone please figure this out? Thank you

Sample Data

```
picID    huntID     photo       D_hunt  
-----------------------------------------
72096    20785   DSC_0605.jpg  2015-04-04  
72098    20785   DSC_0586.jpg  2015-04-04  
72100    20775   DSC_1555.jpg  2015-01-02  
72098    20745   DSC_5828.jpg  2014-12-15  
72096    20745   DSC_4632.jpg  2014-12-15
```

Results should be something like this...

```
huntID       photo  
--------------------------
20785       DSC_0605.jpg  
20775       DSC_1555.jpg  
20745       DSC_5828.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the window function, `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT
    huntID,
    photo
FROM(
    SELECT *,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY huntID ORDER BY D_hunt DESC, picID DESC)
    FROM rsPhotos
)t
WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY huntID DESC
```

Comment: Thank you for your knowledge. My Sam's manual didn't have ROW_NUMBER, OVER or PARTITION in it, I will have to look it up on line. What does the "t" do? It doesn't work if it isn't there. Thanks again. Here is what I did with your help. [link](http://www.sdthunters.com/PicturesHunts.asp)